# How to remove firstname, lastname validation (magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, register, persistent

I want only Email, and Password field in registration form **(persistent/customer/form/register)**

**I have also removed rest of the fields.**

Still required validation for Firstname and Lastname is still automatically popping up.

Now how to remove these validation for register page.

Comment: Check this link for it : http://magentosteven.blogspot.in/2015/07/magento-remove-firstname-and-lastname.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the database value for this attribute

Table name : `eav_attribute` In this table find `attribute_code` as `firstname` and change the value of `is_required` to 0. Do same for `lastname`.

Comment: After Change  in the database,validation is showing error in address form. @Ashish Jagnani